# Waiting for any of 2 async methods to return a result

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I'd like to know if I am following the best practices when dealing with asynchronous programing. The problem that I have at hand is this: I am talking to 2 devices at the same time. I can send them messages using a `SendMessageAsync(msg)` method. Both devices received this message at the same time but in return, only one of them sends a reply while the other simply does not answer.

Also the method should accept a `CancellationToken` so that e.g. the whole thing can be cancelled after a timeout or for other reasons.

So I have written this method to read the messages:

```
public async Task<Message> GetMessageAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
    using (var cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(token, new CancellationToken(false)))           
    {
        var device1 = Task.Run(async () => { return await GetDevice1Async(cts.Token); });
        var device2 = Task.Run(async () => { return await GetDevice2Async(cts.Token); });

        var response = await Task.WhenAny(device1, device2);

        cts.Cancel(); //Only one device answers, so cancel the other other one

        return response.Result;
    }            
}
```

I was wondering if my solution is following the best practices. Specifically, I am interested to get very good performance (devices that I talk to are USB devices so I'd like to be able to service them quickly). So I am not very happy about creating two tasks each time I need to read a message.

For the moment it seems my solution works but it has been reported that on some machines, it is running slow. On my machine, however, it is running quite fast so I don't know if it is because of a problem in my code or something else.

Am I doing it right? Is there a way to improve this solution?

Edit:
Based on the suggestion from Jeroen Mostert and usr, I updated the code as follows:

```
public async Task<Message> GetMessageAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
    using (var cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(token, new CancellationToken(false)))           
    {
        var taskList = new List<Task<Message>> {
            GetDevice1Async(cts.Token),
            GetDevice2Async(cts.Token)
        };

        // wait for any operation to finish, then cancel the other one
        var task = await Task.WhenAny(taskList);
        cts.Cancel();

        //ensure both operations are either finished or cancelled before returning
        try {
            await Task.WhenAll(taskList);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        { 
            //The exception is expected as is safe to ignore
        }

        return task.Result;
    }            
}
```

Comment: The way you're using these tasks, I'd think `Task.Run(async () => { return await GetDevice1Async(cts.Token); });` can be simplified to `GetDevice1Async(cts.Token)`. No need to wrap it in another task (unless the method does significant up-front synchronous work).

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Good catch. I don't remember why I thought I need to wrap the call in a `Task`. Anyway, it tested your suggestion and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, this is fine.

One problem, though, is that you're always abandoning one task. It is requested to cancel itself but if it does not do that it will continue to run. This can accumulate resource usage and might account for the slowness that you are seeing.

In .NET IO rarely is cancellable easily. For example with sockets you can't cancel an IO other than closing the socket. When talking to your USB device you need to make sure that cancellation will indeed work.

A different problem is that the `cts` is disposed possibly after the last usage of its tokens. At the time you call `cts.Dispose()` there's still one task running that *might* register itself with the token. I'm not sure if that is guaranteed to work.

You can fix this by waiting for the cancelled operation to actually cancel:

```
    cts.Cancel();
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks); //Maybe need to swallow exceptions.
    return response.Result;
```

---

You can possibly simplify `Task.Run(async` to just the normal method call. This changes semantics a bit. It passes the sync context through and it executes some part of the async method synchronously. You might or might not want that. It is not a significant efficiency problem. My subjective assessment is that this `Task.Run` pattern clarifies the code and makes the code easier to get right.

Comment: Good point. The chain of calls for the `GetDevice1Async()` end up with a call to `FileStream.ReadAsync()` but you are right, it is better to be sure that the cancellation has actually been completed before going any further.

Comment: You probably can/should add `ct.Register(() => stream.Dispose())`. I don't know whether this will abort the IO or not. Some IOs are not cancellable at all. For sockets this is the way to go. I can't vouch for other IO types.

Comment: I'll check to ensure I am disposing the streams correctly but I don't open/close streams for passing each message. Cancelling `ReadAsync` for the USB devices seems to work but as you mentioned, I might need to ensure cancellation is finished before reading from the same stream again.